# Asynchronous task that DOES NOT block the thread when it is idle

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am building a game engine that has a standard loop (update/draw is called 60 times per second). I need a background task that will do work while my main thread is busy. I have a limited knowledge in concurrency and here are the options I could come up with:

OPTION A:

```
    // Runs once.
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Scene.BGThreadTrigger = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        Scene.BGTask = Task.Run((Action)Scene.BGThreadFunction);
    }

    // Runs 60 times per second.
    protected override void Update()
    {
        BGThreadTrigger.Set();
    }
    public static ConcurrentQueue<Action> BGThreadTaskContainer = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    public static Task BGEventWait()
    {
        BGThreadTrigger.Wait();
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }

    public static async void BGThreadFunction()
    {
        Action action;
        while (ZHiGame.GameIsRunning && SceneIsAlive)
        {
            await BGEventWait();

            while (BGThreadTaskContainer.TryDequeue(out action))
                action();
            BGThreadTrigger.Reset();
        }
    }
```

OPTION B:

```
    public static ConcurrentQueue<Action> BGThreadTaskContainer = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    // Runs 60 times per second.
    protected override void Update()
    {
        Scene.BGTask = Task.Run((Action)Scene.BGThreadFunction);
    }    

    public static async void BGThreadFunction()
    {
        Action action;
        while (BGThreadTaskContainer.TryDequeue(out action))
            action();
    }
```

I would like to know an opinion of experienced coders who work with concurrency - what is the most optimal way to implement this.

**UPDATE:** I need the code in BGThreadFunction be executed strictly at a particular point in time - when the Draw() method is executing. The restrictions I am facing fore the Draw() method to be executed only on the main thread. But there is work that can be done, while it is executing, so what I need is a way to collect that work (a container) and a way to trigger it's execution at a given point of time. I do not need a container that executes tasks asynchroniously once they are added, because usually when they are added (and my example, sadly does not show it) all the threads are busy, and even if they are not, I still need a way to controll when the container is being emptied and processed.

**UPDATE:** After the comments received, I managed to create the following system:

```
    public static ActionBlock<Action> WorkerBlock;
    // Runs once.
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Scene.BGThreadTrigger = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        Scene.BGTask = Task.Run((Action)Scene.BGThreadFunction);
    }

    public static ConcurrentQueue<Action> BGThreadTaskContainer = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    // Runs 60 times per second.
    protected override void Update()
    {
        Action action;

        // This way I signal the start of the background work each frame.
        while (BGThreadTaskContainer.TryDequeue(out action))
            WorkerBlock.Post(action);
    }
```

**UPDATE:** I also tried this solution:

```
    Thread BGThread;

    // Runs 60 times per second.
    protected override async void Update()
    {
        if (BGThread != null)
            BGThread.Wait();
        BGThread = Task.Run((Action)WhileDrawIsExecuted);
    }


    public static void WhileDrawIsExecuted()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(BGThreadTaskContainer, action =>
        {
            action();
        });
        Action completedAction;
        while (BGThreadTaskContainer.TryDequeue(out completedAction)) ;
    }
```

I think this one is the better one, but I am not sure if Task.Run() is safe to call so often (60 times per second).

Comment: Why not have the background task *continually* dequeue actions? Instead of telling it to dequeue all actions after 60 times a second.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Tasks aren't threads, and .NET has its own mechanisms for animation, eg in WPF or DirectX. If you want to process data posted to a queue asynchronously, check the [ActionBlock<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx)  class and the TPL Dataflow in general. The library is made specifically to asynchronously process a continuous stream of data in a pipeline of  steps.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please read my update. Btw I have just installed .Net 4.6 and my console project is configured for .net 4.5.1 profile, but I cannot add ActionBlock<> into my code - System.Threading.Tasks does not contain the .Dataflow namespace! Does it mean I need to use a higher Visual Studio version (I have VS 13)?

Comment: No, you need to [add the appropriate library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx), either from References or NuGet. NuGet is preferable as it contains the latest version. Check the MSDN section on [DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) as well

Comment: Anyway, *why* are you trying to handle the drawing of individual frames? This is a job for WPF transitions and/or Direct X, not a job for an application's message loop (that's what calls Draw)

Comment: Which library should I add? I did not see any Dataflow library in references. You are talking about the project's Referecnes section in Visual Studio's project properties window right?

Comment: What do you mean handle the drawing of individual frames? I am working with XNA 4.0 and it's Game class has built-in Draw() and Update() methods which I override. However, I know that DirectX 9 (which is what XNA 4.0 uses) does drawing on the main thread only. So I want to occupy other threads with useful work in the mean time (for instance I am updating my skeletal animation in there). In the Update() method I update all of my objects with Parallel.Foreach() method - so, as far as I know about TPL, all the threads are occupied.

Comment: I managed to add the library - I never used NuGet before. I downlaoded and installed Task Parallel Library from the Microsoft/.Net hub with NuGet.

Comment: "In the Update() method I update all of my objects with Parallel.Foreach() method" So that's what you are doing now? and that's your ultimate solution? Or you have a problem with that?

Comment: @weston in Update I run only the code that cannot run simultaneously with the Draw code, I still need the solution for the code that runs during the Draw call. So far I am using the last solution. I am testing it right now, I am not quite sure yet if it is the best way to go.